# Error al procesar cubo multidimensional OLAP

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

**Buenas tardes, estoy intentando procesar mi cubo multidimensional olap pero me aparece una serie de errores al procesarlo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Anteriormente estuve batallando con otro error relacionado a la instancia de sql server analysis services, instalé una nueva instancia multidimensional y se solucionó, pero ahora tengo esos errores, soy nueva en el tema y llegue a eso viendo videos de youtube, no se que podria ser ):**

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema de conexión entre tu instancia de Analysis Services y tu base de datos. Regenera el Datasource y confirma que la conexión sea exitosa.

Comment: No se incluyeron los errores. Sin embargo, es mejor que edites tu pregunta para agregar detalles y no se pierdan en los comentarios.

Comment: Saludos, Agradezco mucho tu respuesta. Revisé el datasource y la conexión se ejecuta correctamente: 
TÍTULO: Administrador de conexiones
------------------------------

Se probó correctamente la conexión.

------------------------------
BOTONES:

Aceptar
------------------------------
Sin embargo, volví a realizar los mismos pasos en un nuevo proyecto en mi visual studio, esta vez los errores son los siguientes:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HDOgpP-SVLFZimBIkeaQdazBUTc75w3V/view?usp=sharing 

Agradecería mucho si me pudiera ayudar con eso. Gracias!! 

Comment: Perdón, lo borré y lo hice de nuevo ya que no me dejó editar

Comment: Siguen siendo errores de conexión. Esto es un error de configuración que no podemos solucionar en un sitio de preguntas y respuestas.